# How to setup nodejs's nodemailer for two use cases in a project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nodemailer

This is the code I have for one use, which is for my contact page.

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const path = require('path');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

const app = express();

// View engine setup
app.engine('handlebars', exphbs());
app.set('view engine', 'handlebars');

// Static folder
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '')));

// Body Parser Middleware
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.render('contact');
});

app.post('/send', (req, res) => {
  const output = `
      <li>Name: ${req.body.name}</li>
      <li>Email: ${req.body.email}</li>
      <li>Phone: ${req.body.phone}</li>
    <p>${req.body.message}</p>
  `;

  // create reusable transporter object using the default SMTP transport
  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
    port: 25,
    secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
    auth: {
        user: 'EMAIL', // senders email
        pass: 'PASSWORD' // senders email password
    },
    tls:{
      rejectUnauthorized:false
    }
  });

  // setup email data with unicode symbols
  let mailOptions = {
      from: '"xyz Team" <xyz@info.com>', // sender address
      to: req.body.email, // receiver or receivers
      subject: 'xyz Support', // Subject line
      html: output // html body
  };

  // send mail with defined transport object
  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
      if (error) {
          return console.log(error);
      }
      console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);   
      console.log('Preview URL: %s', nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));

      res.render('contact', {msg:'message.'});
  });
  });

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server started...'));
```

What I want is, without having to rewrite and duplicate all this code again, to use for another page which I want to send the values that are submitted to a form. What is the most convenient way I could achieve this?

Comment: Create your own Nodemailer user class, you instantiate and use as needed.

Comment: You can create another file, and have your custom methods wrapping nodemailer's methods in there. Then you can require your file and call your methods so you don't need to duplicate the code.